# My baked textures are black. ( file included )

Tags: texture-baking

I have tried everything for the last two days, even exported and imported back into a new file and I am just a mess over this because I cannot figure out why my texture baked black.

I have included the new file I created as well as the old file.Both are a mess. I am new to blend for forgive my ignorance.

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3c7thoxqnwhhw90/Lipstick%20Blend%20v2-Question.blend?dl=0

This is the one I had issues with; It's probably an absolute mess but, I thought if I remove the object from this file it would be better, but, it's not...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztknxbwxlur8xok/Lipstick.blend?dl=0

Help please

Comment: Instead of making your question rely entirely on  downloading your file and asking folks to reverse-engineer, it is useful if you add a few images that show your current scene materials along with a description the way you have been baking your textures. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: Hi Cegaton, I went ahead and added a picture, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried rendering and I noticed that there were no light in your scene, you are trying to bake the difusse color of your object without a light that can make the program recognize it's color, I've tried different things for the baking and I realized a few things.

1) I checked the normals of your model and realized that inside of your models are some parts which can't receive light, I did the unwrap a second time and noticed how it changed.

[image]

After that, I tried to bake and the problem persisted.

2) The other thing I noticed was the fact of no light in your scene, that's probably the biggest reason of why your bake was totally black.

What did I do was to bring a lot of world light in order to make the bake successful and noticed that it worked, one thing you should try when baking in Cycles Blender is to enable the world light so you can properly bake the textures with correct shadows and ambient occlusion. In fact it is preferable to have world light instead of using multiple light spots like lamps, suns, etc.

Here is an small tutorial of how to turn on world light.

Go to the world tab in the properties panel and follow as the screenshots show.

[image]->
[image]

Here's the bake result, the exposed faces of the model received the world light so they changed.

[image]

Comment: D; my second blend file had world light enabled and it still baked black. I will try this technique and see if it works. Thank you so much for a detailed response

Comment: This actually worked! Thank you so much. I see using environment lighting helps instead of regular lighting in the scene. Awesome